# Query Firebase with ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I start in the development in ionic with firebase and I am confronted with a little worries. Here is my database. I would like to display all the rooms of which user X is a member. In each group there is a table for the list of members. But I can list all the rooms.

```html
"rooms" : {
    "-Kq-SLPGXoyW5bn8384X" : {
      "createdAt" : 1501098764132,
      "group_dp" : "img_base64",
      "groupname" : "PDCI",
      "members" : [ "10", "11", "12" ],
      "ownerId" : "10",
      "type" : "groupe"
    },
    "-Kq-StfFDhhuOgMhNrae" : {
      "createdAt" : 1501098908584,
      "group_dp" : "img_base64",
      "groupname" : "Echo",
      "members" : [ "10", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18" ],
      "ownerId" : "10",
      "type" : "onetoone"
    }
  }
```

```js
function Rooms($firebaseArray, UserService, firebase, $localStorage, $sessionStorage) {
    var currentUser = UserService.getProfile();
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    var rooms = $firebaseArray(ref.child('rooms'));

    return {
        all: function() {
            rooms.$loaded().then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                angular.forEach(response, function(room) {
                    ref.child('room-messages').child(room.$id)
                        .orderByChild("createdAt")
                        .limitToLast(1)
                        .on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
                            room["last_message_content"] =  snapshot.val().content;
                        });
                })
            });

            return rooms;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), the best solution would be to have multiple trees; one for rooms and one for members. In the members tree list all of the rooms that they are part of as you have in the rooms tree. When you need to know all the rooms a member is part of just reference that specific member entry and then get the data through the room entry.